# Generate unique 32bit number from two 96bit numbers

Tags: c++, arm, stm32

For idntification of a device, i need a unique number (32bit). I'm using a STM32 Microcontoller and and an NFC Reader Chip which both provide a unique 96bit numbers

Both 96bit numbers cannot be shrinked of offset, because the suppliers do not share the composition of the 96 bit number - probably to identify counterfeit products.

For the current MCU i extracted the following data:

> **MCU 1**
>
> 0-31bit  = 0x410024
>
> 32-63bit = 0x3848500c
>
> 64-96bit = 0
>
> **MCU 2**
>
> 0-31bit  = 0x5f0027
>
> 32-63bit = 0x3848500c
>
> 64-96bit = 0

The content is described as following in the datasheet:

> 0..31 Silicon Wafer XY positiones (so there will be duplicateds here for 
>   every single waver)
>
> 32   Wafer Number of Lot
>
> 33..96 Lot Number

So apparently the two examples above are same lot, same wafer, only different position, which makes sense because they were taken from the same reel

For the NFC Reader i extracted the following

> **NFC Reader**
>
> 0-31bit  = 0x34471725
>
> 32-63bit = 0x53484835
>
> 64-96bit = 0x38301531

The reader has zero information how the numbers are composed.

My question here is, if it would be possible to generate a new unique 32bit number fromt hese two 96bit numbers. The number can be any, it must not have relation to the original numbers, but should be as unique as possible.

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Obviously, creating a unique 32-bit number is impossible (there are more 96-bit numbers than 32-bit numbers). If you don't want to utilize additional information about the distribution of bits, simply extracting 32 bits from the 96 is as good as any other approach (in the sense that the probability of collisions is equal).

Comment: Lot numbers are numerical, but still given in ASCII, X and Y positions are given in BCD format. You can use this to compress the information contained a bit, although not as much as you desire...

Comment: Hi Aconcagua, do you have proof that this is the case? Would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If there is a random chance of collision, its probability would increase roughly exponentially with each unit. This is known as the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

For 100,000 items,
[image] gives 0.6878 (courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%28%282%5E32-1%29%2F%282%5E32%29%29%5E%28100000+choose+2%29)) i.e. more than 68%. For 10,000 items, it's [barely over 1%](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%28%282%5E32-1%29%2F%282%5E32%29%29%5E%2810000+choose+2%29). Play around with the numbers, and see whether you can take the risk.

---

For guaranteed results, i'd add an inexpensive **serial number EEPROM**, such as the [24AA02UID](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/24AA02UID) to the device.

Answer (score 0):

> would be possible to generate a new unique 32bit number from these two 96bit numbers [...]  be as unique as possible.?

Yes, you'll want to use a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) that maps your two 96-bit integers to a `uint32_t` with as little chance of collisions as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd just SHA1 the concatenation of both numbers and truncate the result to 32 bits. You'd have a very good balance between collision chance/randomness and hashing speed that way.

Answer (score 0):

@berendi made a good point but to answer directly to your question, most STM32 MCUs embed a hardware CRC. CRC32 returns a 32 bits hash so it's probably what you need.